# How to use email_template_directory for UserForm?

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have added this to my config.yml to configure custom directory path of my email template

```
UserDefinedForm:
  email_template_directory: themes/ellisco/templates/Useremails/
```

then added a SS File on themes/ellisco/templates/Useremails. Unfortunately, my newest added template was not able to read. Any idea what is missing or my mistake?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the namespace for UserDefinedForm: `SilverStripe\UserForms\Model\UserDefinedForm`. I think that's all you'll need to do.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the missing piece. 

`SilverStripe\UserForms\Model\UserDefinedForm:`
 `email_template_directory: mysite/templates/useremails/`

I have added that.. but it can't detect the file under themes/mysite/templates/useremails.

Comment: Which version are you using? I think there was a bug with it not using frontend themes recently

Comment: I'm using version 5.4 on SS4